# Upgrading from a nVidia 650 TI to something more beefy

Tags: graphics-cards

I bought Assassin's Creed: Syndicate last night and found that my graphics card was *really* struggling with it. The card itself is at least 2 years old (I bought it with my first paycheck in 2013) and was second hand/refurbished even then. It's had a good life, but I'm ready to give it a viking funeral.

My current hardware specs are as follows:

- Intel i5-i3570 3.4ghz (can be overclocked to 4ghz)
- 24GB DDR3 RAM @ 1333mhz (don't ask)
- 2TB Seagate Internal HDD (Not sure if that is entirely relevant - disk speeds aren't as fast as my SSD but I don't want to put something as beefy as AC on an SSD)
- Gigabyte GA-Z77-D3H motherboard (http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4140#ov)
- Can't remember exact model of the PSU but I believe it is 700W.. it is, at lowest, 500W.

And, of course, the nvidia 650 Ti with 2GB graphics memory.

I'd ideally like to play at a steady 40+fps @ 1920x1080 on at least medium settings - right now the game is pretty choppy in terms of FPS especially in some scenes.

I understand, of course, that the AC games are known for their.. lack of optimisation :(

I'd be willing to stretch to about £250, which is *just under* the cost of [this card](http://www.ebuyer.com/663848-msi-gtx-970-gaming-twin-frozr-v-4gb-gddr5-dual-dvi-hdmi-gtx-970-gaming-4g) but anything more would be pushing it.

Ebuyer links would be preferred as they do next day delivery ;-)

Comment: You can go with the MSI GTX 970 you linked to. This card should achieve pretty high settings with good 50fps. Make sure that you keep an eye on the VRAM usage in AC Syndicate and don't go over 3.5GB or you'll have pretty bad lags :)

Comment: I'm currently going over that much now... woops

Comment: @benjaminS 970 seems like a good idea but it is slightly out of my budget range. Whilst I would go for it if it is really just *that* good, I would prefer to see if there is anything lower first :p

Comment: You have other options.One would be the [R9 380X](http://www.ebuyer.com/729764-powercolor-r9-380x-myst-edition-4gb-gddr5-dual-dvi-hdmi-displayport-pci-e-axr9-380x-4gbd5-ppdhe) or the R9 380 (they perform pretty much the same) which should perform pretty well on 1920x1080 with high to ultra settings on most games(witcher 3 runs awesome on it e.g.). The other option would be the [R9 390 with full 8GB of VRAM](http://www.ebuyer.com/714697-powercolor-pcs-r9-390-8gb-gddr5-dual-link-dvi-d-hdmi-displayport-pci-e-graphics-axr9-390-8gbd5-ppdhe) which will perform on the same level as the 970 /or better

Comment: It would still be good to tell us your PSU - check the label on it if possible. You don't want your PC to get damaged by a cheaper PSU :)

Comment: This is the part where I mention I just bought the 970. I had a discussion with someone in another chat room and realised that if i were to get the 960 (which is a direct downgrade from this) I would eventually want the 970 anyway. I have no particular attachment to nvidia other than the fact I've used them for the longest time. I'm currently not on my PC so I don't know the brand of the PSU unfortunately :( I'm at work. Will check when I get home so you can tell me if it will blow up in my face or not.

Comment: @benjaminS power supply didn't blow up - just don't have the connectors required on it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AMD R9 390 is slightly cheaper than the GTX 970 (£185), and offers similar or better performance in comparison to the Nvidia card you were showing. As a owner of this card myself, I am very pleased with it. Just keep in mind that if your Power Supply is not over 600 watts, you should choose an Nvidia GTX 970, as they use less power. Figuring the wattage of your PSU is easy, just take a look at the side of the unit.

A link to a relatively cheap R9 390 is [here - this](http://www.newegg.com/global/uk/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125792&cm_re=r9_390-_-14-125-792-_-Product) card has a slightly different cooler than the one I got for mine, but has the same overall design. It costs £185.

A link to a cheaper GTX 970 is [here -](http://www.newegg.com/global/uk/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814487088&cm_re=gtx_970-_-14-487-088-_-Product) again, this card is slightly less powerful but uses less power. After putting it in your cart, it should cost £192.

Comment: I've already bought the linked GTX - power supply is 500W. :)